# Check whether a user is logged in

Tags: php, cookies

I've just figured out that my login system was absolutely not secured.

So I thought about something :

- The user try to log in.
- I check in the database if hash(password) = the password hashed in the DB.
- If it is ok, I set a cookie like this:

```
setcookie ("pseudo", $_POST['pseudo'], time() + 36000);
```

- Then, on each "member" page, I check if the user is logged in with :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['pseudo']))
```

But what I don't understand is that anyone can create a cookie named pseudo... So does that mean that I should store the password in a cookie and check on each "member" page the database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use sessions and their variables, they are stored on the server, thus the user cannot change their values.

Read this : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

And this : http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

If your connection is okay, create a session (do any stuff you want to do when a user is connected).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sir. This is exactly what I usually do (I just thought that the user could change a $_SESSION). Since I have to use COOKIE to let the user logged in, I gather that SESSION is for log in, but why do people store password or username inside $_COOKIE ?

Comment: People I know don't store plain text password inside $_COOKIE. ;) Not even a hashed password. Username is usually public, so it seems okay to me to store it into $_COOKIE, but it is not necessary...